# Prove (or disprove ) $ x =(x_1,x_2 ,x_3,\dots , x_n ,0,0 \dots )　$ is a Vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Let $X$ be the sequence space of all sequences of the form 
$$ x =(x_1,x_2 ,x_3,\dots , x_n ,0,0 \dots )　$$
where $\forall i \in \mathbb{N}$ $x_i \in \mathbb{R}$

whose terms are all zero after some index

Prove (or disprove) that $X$ is a vector space

---

$\mathbb{R}^n$ is a vector space on its on. We can show that our $X$ is a sub vecter space being a vector space on its own right.

---

**Sub vector space test**

zero  vector in $X$, closed under addition, closed under scalar mult

---

**Zero vector $\in X$**  we have that $0 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 , 0 ,\dots , 0 \end{pmatrix} \in X$ by defintion

**Closure under addition**
$$
  \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\  \vdots \\ x_n\\ 0 \\ 
\vdots\\  \end{pmatrix} 
     + \begin{pmatrix} y_1 \\  \vdots \\ y_n\\ 0 \\
         \vdots\\  \end{pmatrix} 
= \begin{pmatrix} y_1+x_1  \\  \vdots \\ y_n+ x_n \\ 0 \\
         \vdots\\  \end{pmatrix}  \in X $$

**Closure under scalar** 
$$a \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\  \vdots \\ x_n\\ 0 \\ 
\vdots\\  \end{pmatrix} 
=   \begin{pmatrix} ax_1 \\  \vdots \\ ax_n\\ 0 \\ 
\vdots\\  \end{pmatrix}  \in X$$

---

Comment: Needs more work: when you prove closure under addition, you should not assume that $x$ and $y$ have the same value of $n$ without justification.  Two random elements of $X$ need not have the same number of non-zero components.

Comment: Yeah,  kind of assumed that for X that the 0 start after some $i$. I need to be careful on that and elaborate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The addition closure "proof" is wrong: it doesn't have to be $\;n=m\;$, and it should be

$$\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\\ldots\\x_n\\0\\\ldots\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}y_1\\y_2\\\ldots\\\ldots\\y_m\\0\\\ldots\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}x_1+y_1\\x_2+y_2\\\ldots\\0\\\ldots\end{pmatrix}$$

in the right side, the last possibly non-zero entries depend on whether $\;n>m\;$ or $\;n<m\;$ .